# Format Code MS Visual Studio for C# Console project Not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Excuse me, 
I use Ms Visual Studio 2010.
I try to follow many suggestion at this case, but I am still failed to make this functionality working well..
This is my code, still not formated well:
[image: not-working]

This is my setting for C#:
[image: setting indent]

[image: setting 2]

should I move to another IDE? 
I am familiar with intellij idea and netbeans IDE. But that IDE not supported C# Development...
Any sugestion?

Thank You

Comment: use Ctrl+K+D for formatting code. its defaultly not formates code you need to do by your own.

Comment: I can nor read your code snippets since my company blocks images. Can you use the code snippet mechanism that is built into stackoverflow?

Comment: **Blocks images**?! That's crazy :S!

Comment: Sorry, I am use code blocks, stackoverflow maybe re-format the code automatically.. and I have press ctrl K and ctrl D.. It is not working at my IDE

Comment: No, Stack Overflow doesn't reformat automatically.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the problem is in your formatting options.

Under Options / Text Editor / C# / Formatting / Indentation, make sure that the "Indent open and close braces" box is *not* checked. Your code looks like it's formatted perfectly for a configuration where that box *is* checked. This is what my set of options looks like for that dialog:

[image: Indentation options]

Comment: indent open and close braces has been checked, Sir.

Comment: @irhabymailed4u: Well that's why you've got that output. If you don't like the way it looks, uncheck it and reformat your code (Ctrl+E, D).